Keyboard shortcut to show inline diff for current line in JetBrains IDEs
I'm using PyCharm (or other JetBrains IDEs) and I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut to quickly view the changes made to the current line or line context without using the mouse.
Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

The blue change marker appears in the left gutter when a line has been modified.
Clicking this marker with the mouse shows an inline diff for that line.
I want to trigger this inline diff view using a keyboard shortcut instead of the mouse.

I've already tried:

Searching the PyCharm documentation
Looking through the keymap settings



Have you tried Show Diff for Lines? -- pure guess based on the action name.

@LazyOne I tried. It shows the difference in new tab window.

@LazyOne it is Change Under Caret.

You have found one. Nice!!
